# Удаление содержимого элемента с определенным id

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть элемент интерфейса - список `ul` с `id=sidemenu`

```html
<ul id="sidemenu">
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
      <a href="" class="nestedblock">Техника для кухни</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
      <a href="" class="nestedblock">Бытовая техника для дома</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
      <a href="" class="nestedblock">Ноутбуки и компьютеры</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
      <a href="" class="nestedblock">Комплектующие</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Каким образом можно удалить содержимое этого элемента (не сам элемент, а его содержимое) в js и jquery коде (удаление производится в js и jquery коде)?

Comment: что значит удалить содержимое в js,jquery коде?

Comment: думаю innerHtml = ""

Comment: @АлексейШиманский удаление производится в js и jquery коде.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#sidemenu').html(''); // Jquery

document.getElementById('sidemenu').innerHTML = ''; // vanillaJS
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sidemenu">
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
      <a href="" class="nestedblock">Техника для кухни</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
      <a href="" class="nestedblock">Бытовая техника для дома</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
      <a href="" class="nestedblock">Ноутбуки и компьютеры</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
      <a href="" class="nestedblock">Комплектующие</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если на JS делать то можно так

```js
clear.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
   sidemenu.innerHTML = "";
})

clearItems.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
   var items = sidemenu.getElementsByTagName("li");
   [...items].forEach(item => item.innerHTML = "");   
})
```

```html
<ul id="sidemenu">
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
      <a href="" class="nestedblock">Техника для кухни</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
      <a href="" class="nestedblock">Бытовая техника для дома</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
      <a href="" class="nestedblock">Ноутбуки и компьютеры</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="leftside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="centerplace">
      <a href="" class="nestedblock">Комплектующие</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  </li>
</ul>

<button id="clear">Clear All</button>

<button id="clearItems">Clear list data</button>
```